# How to configure the webserver to server a particular page as the default page?

Tags: python, django, lighttpd

I am using Lighttpd and Django. I have configured my Lighttpd server to pass all the requests ending with ".psp" extension to Django.

My startup page is a page served through Django, which is accessed as "http://192.168.1.198/home.psp". I want to enable the user to browse this page without writing "home.psp" explicitly in the url i.e. using "http://192.168.1.198"

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You could just redirect `/` to `/home.psp`. Or proxy `/` to `/home.psp` (lil harder), or change django to serve the root page from `/` and force lighttpd to make an exception to your `.psp` rule by forwarding either `^$` OR `.*\.psp` to django. Just some ideas before I go to sleep. GL!

Comment: Why have you configured your server to serve Django pages as `.psp` in the first place? Django isn't PSP, and doesn't need any particular extension.

Comment: The question makes sense, but would you mind posting your Lighttpd configuration as it is now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. Here is what I did:

I had to add a statement inside `url.rewrite-once` block of lighttpd's configuration file like:

```
 url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
        "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
        "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
        "^(/)$" => "/my_project_dir/home.psp",
        "^(/.*)$" => "/my_project_dir$1",
   )
```

Apart from this, I added the following line in my urls.py:

```
(r'^$',my_index_view_name),
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. Thanks everybody for your replies above. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing concepts here between the "old" method of having individual files represent web pages which themselves contain code that is passed off to an interpreter before being sent in a response to how django/frameworks work.

If you're familiar with apache, imagine django as in part taking on the role of mod_rewrite. Django, and other frameworks, have what's called a dispatcher, or routing, mechanism.

Basically, they subscribe to the MVC pattern that says you should separate out the model, controller and view (in django parlance, model, template and view).

Now what then happens is you have a file called `urls.py` in django, which contains a list of routes (urls) and names of methods (usually contained in `views.py`) which handle them. Here's an example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dologin$',       'testapp.views.auth_login',         name="auth-login-uri"),
    url(r'^doopenidlogin$', 'testapp.views.auth_openid_login',  name="auth-openid-login-uri"),
    url(r'^dologout$',      'testapp.views.auth_logout',        name="auth-logout-uri"),
    url(r'^login$',         'testapp.views.loginform',          name="login-form"),
    url(r'^openidlogin$',   'testapp.views.openidloginform',    name="openid-login-form"),
    url(r'^$',              'testapp.views.index',              name="index"),
)
```

Here `testapp` is a python package, `views.py` is a python file and `index` is a django view. The url is constructed from regex, so I can have whatever I want as the url, much how stackoverflow urls are formed.

So basically, you never need file extensions again. I'd strongly suggest getting a good book on django - there are a few around.

Comment: actually, we need to configure lighttpd to serve Django views right? What I believe is that we need to tell lighttpd that this pages should be served through django and others statically through the web server itself, without passing the request to Django? So I use extensions to let lighttpd identify which requests to pass to Django.. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @mahendraliya That solution is fine, but it's uncommon, and there might be a more elegant way to handle it. For example, you could set all requests that begin with `/media/` to use your static directory as a document root and serve the files directly. You could do the same thing with a virtual host (`media.mysite.com`). Then, all requests to the main domain or without `/media/` would be passed through to Django. This gets rid of any need for extensions and keeps your URLConf cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is the [index-file.names](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Index-file-names.Details) directive in Lighty's configuration file. Just add "home.psp" to the list in your configuration file, and Lighty will look for it when no filename is specified.